# Colorize cells containing data in a selected range

Tags: excel, vba

Does someone know how to realize the following?

I have selected a range of cells in an Excel sheet. After pressing a shortcut key, each cell in the selected range that contains data shall have fill color red.

There seems not to be a default Excel functionality for that but perhaps it can be done with VBA?

Unfortunately, the following code does not work as expected:

```
Sub ColorizeCells()
    Dim Data As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Set Data = Selection

    For Each cell In Data
        If Not cell.Value Is Nothing Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Any suggestions on this are highly appreciated.

Comment: What about conditional formatting? The formula could be, for example, `A2<>""`?  What have you tried?

Comment: There are tons of option available on [**internet**](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+vba+change+cell+color+in+range+if+cell+contains+value&oq=excel+vba+change+cell+color+in+range+if+cell+contains+value&aqs=chrome..69i57.23423j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=excel+vba+change+cell+color+in+range). Have you tried any?

Comment: @ManishChristian Most of them do use conditional formatting which I have tried but tried but did not really like. The remaining ones do not take into acound that only the cells within a predefined shall be considered.

Comment: Share some dummy data and code that you've tried so far.

Comment: @ManishChristian Done.

Comment: `If Len(cell.Value) > 0 Then`

Comment: Have you tried to change your `If` statement with what @TimWilliams have suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint of Tim Williams did the trick. Thanks!

The following code works:

```
Sub ColorizeCells()
    Dim Data As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Set Data = Selection

    For Each cell In Data
        If Len(cell.Value) > 0 Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```